# More than a million tracks inside an object - MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, relational-database, database, nosql

I have a list of users in MongoDb, and each user has loads of 'position tracks'. Which one would be the best way to save them inside this user?

In mysql, I would create a users table with a userId, another table for position tracks and each track would have the userId to be able to query them. I need to do 'selects' between timestamp ranges and more columns.

How would you do that in mongodb? create a users class and then each user has a "tracks" object with all the tracks inside? The thing is... each object could have more than a million tracks,which is a lot.. and I've seen that the limit per object in Mongodb is 16MB, so I'd be limited.

So, how would you do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When designing for MongoDB, it helps to state the queries/usage you want to do the data to optimize the queries.

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you already know that there will be a lot of tracks for every user, I would go with the same thing as for mysql. One collection for users and another for tracks.

Users

```
{
  _id : 1,
  key : 'some other information about user'
}
```

Tracks

```
{
  userID : 1,
  info : 'trackInformation'
}
```

Without knowing more information about tracks, it is impossible to tell more.

Comment: Hm... so how would I get all the tracks with a timestamp object between 2 ranges? Every user has 1440 tracks per day. If I need to show his weekly path, I would need to get 1440*7 objects from tracks with userID = X and timestmap between 2 ranges.
Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Actually this is a completely different question (so if I will not be able to explain it here, please create a new question). So you can select by date range by using the [following link](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/)

Comment: To add to it, its not a good idea to embed an every increasing subdocument in document. This is because how Mongo stores its object. The cost to updating an every increasing is really high since it has to map the the document to another memory location. Read more here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/